# generic code to fetch supported regions for each aws services using api or nodejs sdk v3

Tags: amazon-web-services

aws-sdk v2 and few initial versions of v3 for javascript aws sdk had built-in method for each class to list supported regions. later versions do not have supported regions methods for each service.

[image]
Much appreciated if any one knows work around.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use the Systems Manager (SSMClient) to get the region information for a service? The [examples in this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) use the CLI but reference being able to use the SDKs as well, so it may be possible. The client you would need is the SSM client, and the [GetParametersByPathCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/ssm/command/GetParametersByPathCommand/). The path below in this CLI example would get you available regions for Athena.

```
    $ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
  --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/athena/regions --output json | \
  jq '.Parameters[].Value'
```

Comment: ```aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/iam/regions --output json --query Parameters[].Value``` shows all regions but on portal only "Global" selected and rest of regions are greyed out.

Comment: Well, Global does mean it is available in all regions, which I believe to be true for IAM. I would suggest trying it with a service that you know is available in a region subset.